# http post request not accepted by php

Tags: php, post, json

I am new to php and stackovrflow. So please pardon my initial mistakes.
I am sending post request through extjs4 app. as per Mozilla console Network tab, request is sent. PHP is 5.4.25. Below are the details:

```
POST /Opp/annt.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 83
Origin: http://localhost
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/opp/index.html?_dc=140
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Form Dataview parsed
aaa=i&bbb=i&ccc=&ddd=&eee=4&fff=5&ggg=&hhh=
```

PHP file:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=openclass", "root", "")  or die("cannot connect to mysql");

    $fileContents = file_get_contents("php://input");
  echo $fileContents;
  json_decode($fileContents, true);

function getPostValue($postData, $fieldName) {
    return (!empty($postData[$fieldName]) ? htmlspecialchars($postData[$fieldName]) : NULL);
}
```

I am not getting any data after post request is executed. Can you pls help in this in pointing out possible issue and solutions

Comment: Isn't data from POST requests cleared from the input and put in the `$_POST` and `$_FILES` arrays?

Comment: @user3855498 What are you trying todo? Almost every line of the php is wrong and does nothing.

Comment: @EWit No, it isn't. It's copied to `$_POST`, but you can use `php://input` to read the raw data.

Comment: `return` should only be used inside a function. `return json_encode($fileContents, true)` makes no sense outside a function. It should `echo json_encode($fileContents, true)`. You shouldn't echo `$fileContents` before that -- if a script is supposed to return `JSON`, that's the only thing it should eecho.

Comment: @Loz I was trying to insert data in mysql through insert statements. Everything was working fine. I made some changes in the way i was sending POST requests and things changed.

Comment: @ Barmar: u r right, edited code

Comment: If you know how to read properly, I wrote I am new to stackverflow. It wasnt necessary to mark it down.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I was getting error because http post was sending form data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 formt. 
I changed the format sent to json using AJAX requests. This changed the format sent across to json key value pairs. 
This helped it read by php.